# Adding Image to XCode Project

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

I'm trying to set an image as a background instead of a color. Here's the code I'm using right now:

```
[testing setBackgroundColor:color];
[testing setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:33]];
```

Is there another [testing set] object to set the background as an image instead of a color? I don't think this is right:

```
[testing setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
testing.backgroundColor = 
[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];
```

another possible solution would be making a UIImageView in your nib/storyboard set the image in the attribute inspector and send to back in Editor > Arrange > send to back

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
[testing setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]]];
```

Personally, I would recommend using a UIImageView instead.

Please note that using colorWithPatternImage will repeat the image to fill the view.